# Глобально отслеживать активацию ссылки

Tags: qt

Существует множество мест, где может появиться ссылка в приложении. Например, в QWebView при нажатии на ссылку в "браузере", в QML при активации ссылки из TextEdit, для QtWidgets в QTextEdit при нажатии на ссылку внутри виджета и т.д.

**Вопрос:** Есть ли способ **глобально** отслеживать нажатие ("переход", активацию) на ссылку по всему приложению?

Требуется отслеживать определенный тип ссылок во всех таких местах, и если ссылка подходит по определенному критерию (например, по регулярному выражению), то не открывать её в браузере, а выполнять внутреннее действие в приложении (например, открывать специальное окно).
Так как таких мест, где может появиться эта ссылка много, то писать для каждого компонента свой обработчик нажатия на ссылку неудобно.

Например, псевдокод:

```
QGuiApplication::eventFilter(...event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LinkActivated) {
         emit linkActivated(event->url());
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#setUrlHandler - подходит?

Comment: Спасибо, как раз тоже нашёл этот класс и изучаю его возможности